# How to sort a csv file with timestamp using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, csv

I am new to unix and I want to create a script to sort the lines inside a csv file based on the timestamp given as a field and then choose the latest line of the csv file and redirect it to a new csv file...

sample csv file:

```
abc,def,ghi,2014/10/10_15:44:32:55
as,dsj.sdk.2014/10/15_13:21:44:32
asas,asas,dfdf,2013/11/16_21:14:18:16
```

Please do provide an in detail explanation to the written commands in the script

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what have you tried? it's always important to line out your previous approaches, and why you ask instead of trying further.

Comment: i tried using sort command but it only sorts date fields which are / separated but when i pipe it to sort using : delimiter it looses its prev result..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
sort --field-separator=',' --key=4 -n test.txt
```

Which means you are separating each line by comma (","), sorting on field 4 and sorting it by numbers.